# Word Doc File to JSON

Tags: java, json, base64, apache-poi, doc

I will be  parsing and converting a document in ms word format to JSON (or by via an XML finally to JSON). How such parsing and conversion will take care of image embeded in word doc. how this images can be represented in json format. Any pointers or demo example.

I am thinking of using apache poi as parser and customised java class for json string builder.

Is there any readily available tool for such parsing and conversion.

Comment: Your question does not contain enough detail for being answered.

Comment: @MatthiasSteinbauer alas!!... some one just answered.... I dint ask for an answer I asked for a brief pointer.. how it could be achieved technologically.... anyways cheers mate.. i got my answer from Tom Godz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert MS Document to Base64 (sequence of ASCII characters) and send it as a String via JSON or XML. Then you can decode it, the document should be the same (with embedded images).

Answer (score 1):

Just .zip the word file, a .docx file is nothing but a collection of xml. You'll find xml files after you open your .zip file. Then convert your xml file into json via google feed API.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Maybe instuctions?

Comment: open your docx file in 7z

Comment: then then you'll see a word folder, open it. Then you'll see a document.xml
now this your ms word data in .xml format